# How to efficiently draw a bitmap 36 times at different locations?

Tags: java, android

I need to draw multiple bitmaps of an identical bitmap source onto a canvas. instead of calling 36 different objects as i am doing right now is there an easier way to draw them all on? And also being able to classify which one is which?

an example of what i want to do is...

i want 36 balls to be drawn on the canvas and have 3 moved everytime i touch the screen.

I currently am doing this by calling 36 different objects of the same drawing but i am looking for a more efficient way to do this.

ESSENTIALLY: Is there a way i can efficiently draw 36 identical bitmaps in different locations on a canvas and move each one specifically onTouch without calling 36 different objects?
Anyone?

Comment: Then you have to store the coordinates of bitmaps drawn depending on touch coordinates you should change bitmap coordinates